# My database didn't update

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

```
<?php
    $db = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'chatting');
    $query = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE state = 1 AND getp = 0";
    $result = $db->query($query);
    $num_result = $result->num_rows;

    $mems = "";
    for ($i = 0; $i < $num_result; $i++) {
        $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
        $mems = $row["userName"] . " " . $mems;
        $query = "update `user` set `getp` = 1 where 'userName` = ".' $row["userName"] ';
        $result = $db->prepare($query);
    }
    echo $mems; 
?>
```

What I want I want to get all records that state = 1 and getp = 0, then inside loop and for every record I want to change the value of getp to 1, It's correct but don't know where is the wrong.

Comment: Echo out that second `$query`. Your quoting is wrong - you're missing the first backtick on `userName` for one. Also, you're just preparing the query, and never actually running it.

Comment: What kind of error you are taking?

Comment: @maverabilisim the value of getp in my database never change!!

Comment: Are you work in localhost?

Comment: 1. you are misusing prepared statements; 2. you can do it with a single query, `UPDATE table SET getp = 1 WHERE condition`.

Comment: BTW, you probably totally missed the point in using *prepared statements*. Prepared statements allow to *prepare* a query, keeping *placeholders* instead of actual values for some parameters. When you execute the prepared statement, the placeholders are "replaced" by the value you passe *at that time*. You could think of it at some kind of "query template". Here, you prepare the same query again and again in your loop. But didn't use any placeholder... in fact you didn't *execute* your query. See here for a basic introduction to that topic http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Please set your update command to:

```
$query = "update `user` set `getp` = 1 where `userName` = '". $row["userName"]. "'";
```

Comment: Warning: Unexpected character in input: ''' (ASCII=39) state=1 in C:\AppServ\www\Last\chat\getOnlineMembers.php on line 11

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end in C:\AppServ\www\Last\chat\getOnlineMembers.php on line 15

Comment: I missed ". Please try again.

Comment: This is completely the wrong way to do this because `$row["userName"]` is not properly escaped. The correct answer is the one with the `bind_param` call.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to `execute()` the update statement..

Also, note that this is not the correct way to prepare statements.. you will have to do something like this:

```
 $query = $db->prepare("update `user` set `getp` = 1 where `userName` = :userName");
 $query->bind_param(':userName',$row["userName"]);
 $result = $query->execute();
```

Comment: Fatal error: Call to a member function execute() on a non-object in C:\AppServ\www\Last\chat\getOnlineMembers.php on line 13

Comment: This should be the way to do it. Are you sure you don't have a typo? If the `bind_param` call succeeded, then the `execute` call should be valid. It's not possible to get that far if it isn't.

Comment: @tadman I agree.. the accepted answer doesn't protect from injection and I can't understand how it worked for OP without execute()..

Answer (score -1):

Why doing it in a for loop? You could just do `UPDATE`user`SET getp = 1 WHERE state = 1 AND getp = 0;`

While looping with for $i++? Why not `while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) { ... }`?

However change the query to

```
$query = 'update `user` set `getp` = 1 where userName = "'. $row["userName"] .'"';
```

and don't forget to execute() it.